# Non-var declaration immediately followed by reassignment

Tags: pine-script

## Source code

Here's an excerpt from the [ADX and DI for v4](https://www.tradingview.com/script/VTPMMOrx-ADX-and-DI/) indicator:

```
//@version=4

study("ADX and DI for v4")
len = input(14)
th = input(20)

TrueRange = max(max(high-low, abs(high-nz(close[1]))), abs(low-nz(close[1])))

SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0
SmoothedTrueRange := nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange
```

## Non-var declaration followed by assignment

In the last two lines, note that `SmoothedTrueRange` is declared and then immediately reassigned:

```
SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0
SmoothedTrueRange := nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange
```

## Question

Why is the `SmoothedTrueRange` declared and then immediately reassigned?

Since there is no `var` on the declaration, it seems this will happen at every bar.

In other words, why isn't the code simply:

```
SmoothedTrueRange = nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you cannot. [Self-referencing](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#self-referenced-variables-are-removed) is not allowed since v3.

So, you first need to declare the variable and then assign a value to it.

It will happen on every bar but with `SmoothedTrueRange[1]`, it will use its value on the previous bar. So, you will have your history as if it was a `var`.

Comment: Great and clear answer. Thank you @vitruvius!

Answer (score 1):

The initial declaration of SmoothedTrueRange with SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0 ensures it has an initial value. Subsequent assignments modify its value based on historical data. Without the initial declaration, it would start with an undefined value, leading to incorrect calculations.